# Player stuck on reactivation - not changing position to spawn

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

I'm writing a script controlling the enter and exit of a space ship in a 2D game.
The problem I'm running into is when exiting the ship, the player is reactivated, and you regain control, but it does not move the player to the empty gameobject I have attached to the ship, in a beginners attempt to move the player to the location of the ship, without ever destroying the player. The player simply spawns on its last known location prior to entering the ship, and I seem to be forced into that location, I can try to move, but its like I'm anchored to that position.

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class SpaceShipActivator : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Takeoff
    public bool inRange;
    public SpaceShipAtmosphereController SpaceShipAtmosphereController;
    public PlayerController playerControl;
    public GameObject Player;
    public bool onBoard;
    //End Takeoff

    //Landing
    public Transform Spawn;
    public Transform landingGear2;
    public Transform landingGear;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;
    float groundRadius = 0.2f;
    bool getIn;
    bool landingGearStable;
    bool landingGearStable2;
    bool shipStable;
    //EndLanding

    Animator anim;


    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        inRange = false;
        SpaceShipAtmosphereController.enabled = false; 

    }


    void Update()
    {

        AnimationUpdate();

        //Launch
        if (inRange && Input.GetButtonDown("Interact") && !onBoard)
        {
            LaunchShip();
        }
        //End launch

        CheckLandingGear();

        //Land
        if(onBoard && Input.GetButtonDown("Roll"))
        {
            LandShip();
        }
        //End Land

    }

    //*********************************Functions**************************************

    void LaunchShip()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Get In", true);
        this.gameObject.tag = "Player";
        SpaceShipAtmosphereController.enabled = true;
        Player.tag = "InactivePlayer";
        playerControl.enabled = false;
        Player.SetActive(false);
        onBoard = true;
    }

    void LandShip()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Get Out", true);
        this.gameObject.tag = "InactivePlayer";
        Player.tag = "Player";
        playerControl.enabled = true;
        SpaceShipAtmosphereController.enabled = false;
        onBoard = false;
        Player.SetActive(true);
        Player.transform.position = Spawn.transform.position;
    }

    void CheckLandingGear()
    {
        //landingGear
        landingGearStable = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(landingGear.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);
        landingGearStable2 = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(landingGear2.position, groundRadius, whatIsGround);

        if (landingGearStable && landingGearStable2)
        {
            shipStable = true;
        }
        //End landingGear
    }

    void AnimationUpdate()
    {
        anim.SetBool("Get In", false);
        anim.SetBool("Get Out", false);
    }

    //For launching ship
    //IF player: inRange enter/exit boolean control.
    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {

        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            //Debug.Log("houi p;gberf");
            inRange = true;
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            inRange = false;
        }
    }
    //End IF player: inRange enter/exit boolean control.


}
```

On a side note, In that same script I've included landingGear, which is set to be two empty gameobjects that basically share Y and are spaced apart on X to check that the spaceship is not only grounded but level for the most part, so the animation doesn't look silly AND to check if the player can even get out. I know this isn't the question, but any input on it would be appreciated, but please don't feel obligated.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Check to make sure you aren't setting the `player.transform.position` over and over somehow, ctrl-f `player.transform.position` in your project and put `print("reposition")` next to each place it's called, play your game, if the word "reposition" shows up in your console several hundreds of times then it's repositioning the player somewhere when it shouldn't be and it will be a logical error.

Comment: Ive spent hours today debugging this, I think its best I walk away for now. I searched every script across my project, and no debug.log would print more then once, as this was my initial thought as well..

Maybe tomorrow I'll look at it in the morning and wonder how I couldn't see the problem

Comment: Yea, I've found sometimes after taking a break I sit down and solve the problem immediately! Sorry I couldn't help more.